# 0x protocol: how to locally sign orders with python

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency

Hi I was following http://0x-contract-wrappers-py.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/,
but can't figure out how i should sign the fill order transaction with my local private key using python. sign_hash() in zero_ex order_utils calls web3.eth.sign(), but where should I pass in private key? Can't find an example or any tutorial.
I use infura so I have to sign the order using local private key.
With normal onchain transaction, these are the steps:

1. build_transaction()
2. sign_transaction() with private key
3. send_raw_transaction()

Since 0x orders are not no chain until they are filled, how do I sign them?